# Resolve Javascript Promise outside the Promise constructor scope

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have been using ES6 Promise.

Ordinarily, a Promise is constructed and used like this

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    if (someCondition){
        resolve();
    } else {
        reject();
    } 
});
```

But I have been doing something like below to take the resolve outside for the sake of flexibility.

```
var outsideResolve;
var outsideReject;
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
    outsideResolve = resolve; 
    outsideReject = reject; 
});
```

And later

```
onClick = function(){
    outsideResolve();
}
```

This works fine, but is there an easier way to do this? If not, is this a good practice?

Comment: I don't think there is another way. I believe it is specified that the callback passed to `Promise` has to be executed synchronously to allow "exporting" the two functions.

Comment: This works for me exactly like you wrote it. So as far as I'm concerned, this is the "canonical" way.

Comment: I think there should be a formal way to achieve this in the future. This feature is very powerful in my opinion as you can wait for values from other contexts.

Comment: Whenever they come up with a proper solution to this problem, I hope they will also make it work for nested promises, some of which may recur.

Comment: I think the Promise API "suggest" to always use them as return values and never as objects that you can access or call. In other words force us to treat them as return values instead of objects we can access or functions we can call or something we can reference with a variable or pass as a parameter, etc. If you start using promises as any other object probably you will end up needing to resolve it from outside like in your question... That being said, I also think there should should be a formal way of doing this... and Deferred seems just a workaround for me.

Comment: @Jose For me it's been useful a couple times, when I need a Promise to resolve immediately after another promise, in cases where Promise.all or Promise.race don't work.

Comment: This pattern will cause a lot of unexpected issues when things start to get complex. Probably a good alternative is to use events in these cases.

Answer (score 268, accepted):

simple:

```
var promiseResolve, promiseReject;

var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
  promiseResolve = resolve;
  promiseReject = reject;
});

promiseResolve();
```

Comment: @ruX, As the accepted answer mentions - it was designed this way on purpose. The point is that if an exception is thrown it will be caught by the promise constructor. This answer (as well as mine) has the pitfall of possibly throwing an exception for whatever code calls `promiseResolve()`. The semantics of a promise are that it *always* returns a value. Also this is functionally the same as OP's post, I don't get what problem this is solving in a reusable way.

Comment: @JonJaques I'm not sure if what you say is true.  The code that calls `promiseResolve()` will not throw an exception.  You can define a `.catch` on the constructor and no matter what code calls it, the constructor's `.catch` will be called.  Here is the jsbin demonstrating how this works: https://jsbin.com/yicerewivo/edit?js,console

Comment: Yeah, it's caught because you wrapped another promise constructor around it - Exactly the point I'm trying to make. However, lets say you have some other code that's trying to call resolve() outside of the constructor (aka Deferred object)... It could throw an exception and not be caught https://jsbin.com/cokiqiwapo/1/edit?js,console

Comment: I see what you mean now, but I don't see how that relates to creating flexible promise resolvers.  If you throw an error outside of something that can catch it, then it doesn't get caught.  This is not a pitfall of a promise pattern.  This is just an example of a bad pattern.

Comment: I am not even sure it is a bad design. An error thrown outside the promise isn't supposed to be caught within the promise. It is perhaps an example of misconception or bad understanding, if the designer actually _expects_ the error to be caught within.

Comment: This exact construct is already mentioned in the question. Did you even read it?

Comment: @carter ,What if the promise was created by `(async()=>{})()`?

Comment: I love the simplicity

Answer (score 166):

Bit late to the party here, but another way to do it would be to use a [Deferred](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/) object. You essentially have the same amount of boilerplate, but it's handy if you want to pass them around and possibly resolve outside of their definition.

*Naive Implementation:*

```
class Deferred {
  constructor() {
    this.promise = new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
      this.reject = reject
      this.resolve = resolve
    })
  }
}

function asyncAction() {
  var dfd = new Deferred()

  setTimeout(()=> {
    dfd.resolve(42)
  }, 500)

  return dfd.promise
}

asyncAction().then(result => {
  console.log(result) // 42
})
```

*ES5 Version:*

```
function Deferred() {
  var self = this;
  this.promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    self.reject = reject
    self.resolve = resolve
  })
}

function asyncAction() {
  var dfd = new Deferred()

  setTimeout(function() {
    dfd.resolve(42)
  }, 500)

  return dfd.promise
}

asyncAction().then(function(result) {
  console.log(result) // 42
})
```

Comment: Do notice the lexical scoping here.

Comment: There is no practical difference in whether `resolve|reject` are assigned lexically or through `bind`. This is just a simple implementation of the [jQuery Deferred](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/) object that has been around since 1.0(ish). It works exactly like a promise, except there is no throw safety. The whole point of this question was how to save a few lines of code when creating promises.

Comment: Using a deferred is the usual way to do this, I have no idea why this isn't higher

Comment: Excellent answer! Was looking for the deferred functionality that jQuery offers.

Comment: Is `Deferred` deprecated?

Comment: @Pacerier in jQuery? probably. This is a clean implementation on top of modern apis though. As you can see there's not much to it.

Comment: I don't know if this is accepted nowdays or not, but it works very well, so I'm fine with it. No problems so far.

Comment: Accepted? meh. Just be aware that if the asyncAction function (thing which creates the deferred object) throws an except during creation, you will not get a promise back. Just be careful about what you're doing ;)

Comment: jQuery was ahead of its time on this lmao

Comment: @JonJaques why "naive"? this looks really nice and simple. I don't think this is incomplete in any way, is it? if so, it would be good to elaborate on why you think this approach is "naive" :-)

Answer (score 127):

No, there is no other way to do this - the only thing I can say is that this use case isn't very common. Like Felix said in the comment - what you do will consistently work.

It's worth mentioning that the reason the promise constructor behaves this way is throw safety - if an exception you did not anticipate happens while your code is running inside the promise constructor it will turn into a rejection, this form of throw safety - converting thrown errors to rejections is important and helps maintain predictable code.

For this throw safety reason, the promise constructor was chosen over deferreds (which are an alternative promise construction way that do allow what you're doing) - as for best practices - I'd pass the element and use the promise constructor instead:

```
var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    this.onclick = resolve;
}.bind(this));
```

For this reason - whenever you *can* use the promise constructor over exporting the functions - I recommend you do use it. Whenever you can avoid both - avoid both and chain.

Note, that you should never use the promise constructor for things like `if(condition)`, the first example could be written as:

```
var p = Promise[(someCondition)?"resolve":"reject"]();
```

Comment: Hi Benjamin! Is there currently no better way of getting yummy promise sugar if we don't know when the promise will be fulfilled yet? Like some sort of asynchronous [wait/notify pattern](http://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/notify-and-wait-example/)?   Like for example, "store", and later invoke a `Promise` chain? E.g. in my particular case, I am on a server, waiting for a specific client reply (a SYN-ACK-kinda hand-shake to make sure the client successfully updated state).

Comment: @Domi check out q-connection and RxJS.

Comment: Hah, as usual, I was too impatient to wait! Either way, it seems like what those libraries are doing is overkill for my particular use-case, unless they are fixing issues that I have overlooked. Mind taking a look at [my minimal solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30014830/2228771)?

Comment: How could do I the same using fetch API?

Comment: Not common? I end up needing it almost every project.

Comment: @TomášZato interesting, I would love to learn about some use cases for this - if you could create some samples on a [gist](https://gist.github.com) I will definitely take a look and forward your concerns to the technical committee.

Comment: I do not see how this last line of code could be considered a good way of writing code. This is very hard to read. I would go for verbose readable way as OP did.

Comment: As for the usecase consider you need to do something after an event is triggered and something else happened. You want to transform event into a promise and unite it with another promise. Seems like a generic problem to me.

Comment: Seems like Promise API was designed to prevent calling resolve() from outside the constructor. But is not uncommon to have more than one "actor" that collaborate to define a async API, one that knows when to install the promise and another that knows how to resolve it. And I don't want to add an emitter in the middle just for this, and the design is not forbidding me to hack it, so, I wonder what would be the correct pattern to use here. Would it be Deferred class as suggested below?  Should I use an event emitter like in the old times and loose async/await syntax ? Any ideas?

Comment: @cancerbero the promise API was designed to be used this way because if the function passed to `new Promise` throws you get a rejected promise. It is also explicitly synchronous and you can rely on the deferred parttern.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - My first use case for this was waiting for fonts to load combined with other async processes.  It allows me to create one callback for the completion of specific combinations of fonts and other code.  I was doing this with 2 global ints: `totalCount` and `loadedCount`.  I would `++loadedCount` in `document.fonts.ready.then()` and in event handlers for async processes.  Now I don't have to keep track of how many processes are in each group.  Beyond font loading, I now use it to create a single callback for multiple AJAX requests. I added an answer with a fonts example.

Comment: p-defer worked for me: https://www.npmjs.com/package/p-defer after this solution worked and I thought maybe there would be something already built out there.

Comment: `this.onclick = resolve;` will cause calling `resolve` function in the promise on every click which might be an overhead since a promise can be resolved only once. Doesn't hurt but also not the most efficient solution. Especially if you are doing it this way was to catch eventual errors which, on this line, will not occur either way.

Comment: Arguably writing `var p = Promise[(someCondition)?"resolve":"reject"]();` might lead to less readable and maintainable code. Of course it depends always on the specific use case but really no need to be fancy here. Such code was written here for example, of course it makes no sense to make a promise that works that way.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - Another use case is if you are communicating with a web worker. If you are expecting multiple pieces of info to arrive via web worker mesages (in an unknown order), it is nice to make a promise p[i] for each piece of info, so consumers of that info could await that promise or register a callback via p[i].then(callme). This promise needs to be resolved by worker.onmessage, not by code provided at promise creation. (Or rejected by code in worker.onerror.) Basically any time an asynchronous process triggers multiple unordered callbacks, you want what the OP is talking about.

Comment: It would be so handy if you could just `var p = new Promise(); p.resolve()`

Comment: @br4nnigan This is both an invalid syntax (you must pass a resolver function) and not supported API (resolve is not exposed nor exist in the returned object).

Answer (score 39):

I liked @JonJaques answer but I wanted to take it a step further.

If you bind `then` and `catch` then the `Deferred` object, then it fully implements the `Promise` API and you can treat it as promise and `await` it and such.

> **⚠️ Editor's Note**: I don't recommend this kind of pattern anymore since at the time of writing, `Promise.prototype.finally` was not a thing yet, then it became a thing… This could happen to other methods so I recommend you augment the promise instance with `resolve` and `reject` functions instead:
>
> ```js
> function createDeferredPromise() {
>   let resolve
>   let reject
>
>   const promise = new Promise((thisResolve, thisReject) => {
>     resolve = thisResolve
>     reject = thisReject
>   })
>
>   return Object.assign(promise, {resolve, reject})
> }
> ```
>
> Go upvote someone else's answer.

```js
class DeferredPromise {
  constructor() {
    this._promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // assign the resolve and reject functions to `this`
      // making them usable on the class instance
      this.resolve = resolve;
      this.reject = reject;
    });
    // bind `then` and `catch` to implement the same interface as Promise
    this.then = this._promise.then.bind(this._promise);
    this.catch = this._promise.catch.bind(this._promise);
    this.finally = this._promise.finally.bind(this._promise);
    this[Symbol.toStringTag] = 'Promise';
  }
}

const deferred = new DeferredPromise();
console.log('waiting 2 seconds...');
setTimeout(() => {
  deferred.resolve('whoa!');
}, 2000);

async function someAsyncFunction() {
  const value = await deferred;
  console.log(value);
}

someAsyncFunction();
```

Comment: I really love this. Thank you. I'm using it as a custom defined component in my Express app, but it'd be great as an NPM module if you were willing to create one, or I could if needed.

This approach is a great mashup of the new async / await and how the old Parse Platform used to approach promises https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_(platform)

Comment: Don’t forget the `Promise.prototype.finally`.

Comment: Good catch @КонстантинВан, I haven't seen this answer in a minute and I don't recommend this anymore. I've updated the answer to reflect

Comment: Well, if you’re worrying about possible future changes in the methods of `Promise`, you could also generalize the mapping work by looping through the properties of `Promise`, no?

Answer (score 32):

A solution I came up with in 2015 for my framework. I called this type of promises **Task**

```
function createPromise(handler){
  var resolve, reject;

  var promise = new Promise(function(_resolve, _reject){
    resolve = _resolve; 
    reject = _reject;
    if(handler) handler(resolve, reject);
  })
  
  promise.resolve = resolve;
  promise.reject = reject;
  return promise;
}


// create
var promise = createPromise()
promise.then(function(data){ alert(data) })

// resolve from outside
promise.resolve(200)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. But what is handler? I had to remove it to get it working.

Comment: @Sahid when you run createPromise() you need to pass a function as argument to it. otherwise the code does not work. You could have an if statement and check for the validity of the handler argument before calling it.

Comment: Thanks for the code! But isn't it possible for some other code to call your `.resolve` before the callback sets it? I'm used to regular threads, not asynchronous events, so I might be a bit confused.

Answer (score 22):

Accepted answer is wrong. It's pretty easy using scope and references, though it may make Promise *purists* angry:

```
const createPromise = () => {
    let resolver;
    return [
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolver = resolve;
        }),
        resolver,
    ];
};

const [ promise, resolver ] = createPromise();
promise.then(value => console.log(value));
setTimeout(() => resolver('foo'), 1000);
```

We are essentially grabbing the reference to the resolve function when the promise is created, and we return that so it can be set externally.

In one second the console will output:

```
> foo
```

Comment: I think this is the best approach. The only thing is that the code could be a bit less verbose.

Comment: Nice! Clever idea. +50 if I could.

Comment: This is just what OP did. In fact you are re-inventing Deferred pattern over Promises, of course this is possible and your approach works (as the initial OP code), but this is not the best practice due to "throw safety reason" described in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 16):

Just in case somebody came looking for a typescript version of a util simplifying this task:

```
export const deferred = <T>() => {
  let resolve!: (value: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void;
  let reject!: (reason?: any) => void;
  const promise = new Promise<T>((res, rej) => {
    resolve = res;
    reject = rej;
  });

  return {
    resolve,
    reject,
    promise,
  };
};
```

This can be used eg. like:

```
const {promise, resolve} = deferred<string>();

promise.then((value) => console.log(value)); // nothing

resolve('foo'); // console.log: foo
```

Answer (score 15):

A helper method would alleviate this extra overhead, and give you the same jQuery feel.

```
function Deferred() {
    let resolve;
    let reject;
    const promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
        resolve = res;
        reject = rej;
    });
    return { promise, resolve, reject };
}
```

Usage would be

```
const { promise, resolve, reject } = Deferred();
displayConfirmationDialog({
    confirm: resolve,
    cancel: reject
});
return promise;
```

Which is similar to jQuery

```
const dfd = $.Deferred();
displayConfirmationDialog({
    confirm: dfd.resolve,
    cancel: dfd.reject
});
return dfd.promise();
```

---

Although, in a use case this simple, native syntax is fine

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    displayConfirmationDialog({
        confirm: resolve,
        cancel: reject
    });
});
```

Answer (score 13):

I'm using a helper function to create what I call a "flat promise" -

```
function flatPromise() {

    let resolve, reject;

    const promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
      resolve = res;
      reject = rej;
    });

    return { promise, resolve, reject };
}
```

And I'm using it like so -

```
function doSomethingAsync() {

    // Get your promise and callbacks
    const { resolve, reject, promise } = flatPromise();

    // Do something amazing...
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('done!');
    }, 500);

    // Pass your promise to the world
    return promise;

}
```

See full working example -

```js
function flatPromise() {

    let resolve, reject;

    const promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
        resolve = res;
        reject = rej;
    });

    return { promise, resolve, reject };
}

function doSomethingAsync() {
    
    // Get your promise and callbacks
    const { resolve, reject, promise } = flatPromise();

    // Do something amazing...
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('done!');
    }, 500);

    // Pass your promise to the world
    return promise;
}

(async function run() {

    const result = await doSomethingAsync()
        .catch(err => console.error('rejected with', err));
    console.log(result);

})();
```

Edit:
I have created an NPM package called [flat-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flat-promise) and the code is also available [on GitHub](https://github.com/arikw/flat-promise).

Answer (score 13):

You can wrap the Promise in a class.

```
class Deferred {
    constructor(handler) {
        this.promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.reject = reject;
            this.resolve = resolve;
            handler(resolve, reject);
        });

        this.promise.resolve = this.resolve;
        this.promise.reject = this.reject;

        return this.promise;
    }
    promise;
    resolve;
    reject;
}

// How to use.
const promise = new Deferred((resolve, reject) => {
  // Use like normal Promise.
});

promise.resolve(); // Resolve from any context.
```

Answer (score 11):

I find myself missing the Deferred pattern as well in certain cases. You can always create one on top of a ES6 Promise:

```
export default class Deferred<T> {
    private _resolve: (value: T) => void = () => {};
    private _reject: (value: T) => void = () => {};

    private _promise: Promise<T> = new Promise<T>((resolve, reject) => {
        this._reject = reject;
        this._resolve = resolve;
    })

    public get promise(): Promise<T> {
        return this._promise;
    }

    public resolve(value: T) {
        this._resolve(value);
    }

    public reject(value: T) {
        this._reject(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this one. I would just change the signature from reject to reject(reason: any)

Answer (score 9):

Many of the answers here are similar to the last example in [this article](http://lea.verou.me/2016/12/resolve-promises-externally-with-this-one-weird-trick/).
I am caching multiple Promises, and the `resolve()` and `reject()` functions can be assigned to any variable or property. As a result I am able to make this code slightly more compact:

```
function defer(obj) {
    obj.promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        obj.resolve = resolve;
        obj.reject  = reject;
    });
}
```

Here is a simplified example of using this version of `defer()` to combine a `FontFace` load Promise with another async process:

```
function onDOMContentLoaded(evt) {
    let all = []; // array of Promises
    glob = {};    // global object used elsewhere
    defer(glob);
    all.push(glob.promise);
    // launch async process with callback = resolveGlob()

    const myFont = new FontFace("myFont", "url(myFont.woff2)");
    document.fonts.add(myFont);
    myFont.load();
    all.push[myFont];
    Promise.all(all).then(() => { runIt(); }, (v) => { alert(v); });
}
//...
function resolveGlob() {
    glob.resolve();
}
function runIt() {} // runs after all promises resolved
```

Update: 2 alternatives in case you want to encapsulate the object:

```
function defer(obj = {}) {
    obj.promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        obj.resolve = resolve;
        obj.reject  = reject;
    });
    return obj;
}
let deferred = defer();
```

and

```
class Deferred {
    constructor() {
        this.promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.resolve = resolve;
            this.reject  = reject;
        });
    }
}
let deferred = new Deferred();
```

Comment: If you're using these examples in an async function, you'll need to refer to the promise property, when you want to use the value of the resolved promise: `const result = await deferred.promise;`

Answer (score 5):

Our solution was to use closures to store the resolve/reject functions and additionally attach a function to extend the promise itself.

Here is the pattern:

```
function getPromise() {

    var _resolve, _reject;

    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        _reject = reject;
        _resolve = resolve;
    });

    promise.resolve_ex = (value) => {
       _resolve(value);
    };

    promise.reject_ex = (value) => {
       _reject(value);
    };

    return promise;
}
```

And using it:

```
var promise = getPromise();

promise.then(value => {
    console.info('The promise has been fulfilled: ' + value);
});

promise.resolve_ex('hello');  
// or the reject version 
//promise.reject_ex('goodbye');
```

Comment: Great... I'm just learning Promises but have been consistently puzzled by the fact that you don't appear to be able to resolve them "somewhere else".  Using a closure to hide implementation details is a great idea... but in fact I'm not sure that's what you've done: rather than have "pseudo" private variables I'm pretty sure there's a way to *completely* conceal the variables which should be inaccessible... which is really what closures mean...

Comment: > A closure is a block of code that can be referenced (and passed around) with access to the variables of the enclosing scope.  var _resolve, _reject; are the enclosing scope.

Comment: yep, fair enough.  Actually it seems to me that my answer is overcomplicating things, and furthermore that your answer can be simplified: you just need to go `promise.resolve_ex = _resolve; promise.reject_ex = _reject;` ... still works fine.

Comment: "*attach a function to extend the promise itself.*" - don't do that. Promises are result values, they should not provide the capability to resolve them. You don't want to pass those extended ones around.

Comment: The question was how to resolve it outside of the scope.  Here is a solution that works, and in our production we have actually had a necessary reason to do it.  I don't see why solving the problem stated deserves a downvote.

Answer (score 4):

In a near future, we will be able to use the native [`Promise.withResolvers()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/withResolvers) which is now at [stade 4](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-promise-with-resolvers?tab=readme-ov-file) and [already implemented in Blink/Webkit based browsers](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_promise_withresolvers) at the time of writing.

In the meantime, I'm using a utility function with the same signature:

```
export default function usePromise<T = void>() {
  const noop = () => {};

  let localResolve: (value: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void = noop;
  let localReject: (reason?: unknown) => void = noop;

  const promise = new Promise<T>((resolve, reject) => {
    localResolve = resolve;
    localReject = reject;
  });

  return {
    promise,
    resolve: localResolve,
    reject: localReject,
  };
}

// Usage
const { promise, resolve, reject } = usePromise();

// Example
const triggerEl = document.querySelector('.trigger');
const someEl = document.querySelector('.dummy-element');

const { promise, resolve } = usePromise();

someEl.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
  resolve();
});

triggerEl.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  someEl.classList.add('fade-out');

  await promise;

  // Wait until transition ends before removing the element
  someEl.remove();
});
```

It is worth mentioning that this is also a valid Vue3 composable.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. By using the `CustomEvent` API for the browser environment. And using an event emitter project in node.js environments. Since the snippet in the question is for the browser environment, here is a working example for the same.

```js
function myPromiseReturningFunction(){
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    window.addEventListener("myCustomEvent", (event) => {
       resolve(event.detail);
    }) 
  })
}


myPromiseReturningFunction().then(result => {
   alert(result)
})

document.getElementById("p").addEventListener("click", () => {
   window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("myCustomEvent", {detail : "It works!"}))
})
```

```html
<p id="p"> Click me </p>
```

I hope this answer is useful!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to everyone who posted in this thread. I created a module that includes the Defer() object described earlier as well as a few other objects built upon it. They all leverage Promises and the neat Promise call-back syntax to implement communication/event handling within a program.

- Defer: Promise that can be resolved failed remotely (outside of its body)
- Delay: Promise that is resolved automatically after a given time
- TimeOut: Promise that fails automatically after a given time.
- Cycle: Re-triggerable promise to manage events with the Promise syntax
- Queue: Execution queue based on Promise chaining.

`rp = require("openpromise")`

https://github.com/CABrouwers/openpromise
https://www.npmjs.com/package/openpromise

Answer (score 3):

Class version, in Typescript :

```
export class Deferred<T> {
    public readonly promise: Promise<T>
    private resolveFn!: (value: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void
    private rejectFn!: (reason?: any) => void

    public constructor() {
        this.promise = new Promise<T>((resolve, reject) => {
            this.resolveFn = resolve
            this.rejectFn = reject
        })
    }

    public reject(reason?: any): void {
        this.rejectFn(reason)
    }

    public resolve(param: T): void {
        this.resolveFn(param)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small lib for this. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@inf3rno/promise.exposed

I used the factory method approach others wrote, but I overrode the `then`, `catch`, `finally` methods too, so you can resolve the original promise by those as well.

Resolving Promise without executor from outside:

```
const promise = Promise.exposed().then(console.log);
promise.resolve("This should show up in the console.");
```

Racing with the executor's setTimeout from outside:

```
const promise = Promise.exposed(function (resolve, reject){
    setTimeout(function (){
        resolve("I almost fell asleep.")
    }, 100000);
}).then(console.log);

setTimeout(function (){
    promise.resolve("I don't want to wait that much.");
}, 100);
```

There is a no-conflict mode if you don't want to pollute the global namespace:

```
const createExposedPromise = require("@inf3rno/promise.exposed/noConflict");
const promise = createExposedPromise().then(console.log);
promise.resolve("This should show up in the console.");
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a library called `manual-promise` that functions as a drop in replacement for `Promise`. None of the other answers here will work as drop in replacements for `Promise`, as they use proxies or wrappers.

`yarn add manual-promise`

`npn install manual-promise`

```js
import { ManualPromise } from "manual-promise";

const prom = new ManualPromise();

prom.resolve(2);

// actions can still be run inside the promise
const prom2 = new ManualPromise((resolve, reject) => {
    // ... code
});


new ManualPromise() instanceof Promise === true
```

https://github.com/zpxp/manual-promise#readme

Answer (score 1):

Just another solution to resolve Promise from the outside

```
 class Lock {
        #lock;  // Promise to be resolved (on  release)
        release;  // Release lock
        id;  // Id of lock
        constructor(id) {
            this.id = id
            this.#lock = new Promise((resolve) => {
                this.release = () => {
                    if (resolve) {
                        resolve()
                    } else {
                        Promise.resolve()
                    }
                }
            })
        }
        get() { return this.#lock }
    }
```

#### Usage

```
let lock = new Lock(... some id ...);
...
lock.get().then(()=>{console.log('resolved/released')})
lock.release()  // Excpected 'resolved/released'
```

Answer (score 1):

If (like me) you don't like augmenting native instances, nor unwieldy **".promise"** properties ... but do love proxies and mangling classes, then this one is for you:

```js
class GroovyPromise {
  constructor() {
    return new Proxy(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.resolve = resolve;
      this.reject = reject;
    }), {
      get: (target, prop) =>
        this[prop] || target[prop].bind(target),
    });
  }
}
```

Used like so:

```js
const groovypromise = new GroovyPromise();
setTimeout(() => groovypromise.resolve('groovy'), 1000);
console.log(await groovypromise);
```

Of course you can also rename the class to something dull like **"Deferred"**

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a function to hijack the reject and return it ?

```
function createRejectablePromise(handler) {
  let _reject;

  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    _reject = reject;

    handler(resolve, reject);
  })

  promise.reject = _reject;
  return promise;
}

// Usage
const { reject } = createRejectablePromise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('resolved')
    resolve();
  }, 2000)

});

reject();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've put together a gist that does that job: https://gist.github.com/thiagoh/c24310b562d50a14f3e7602a82b4ef13

here's how you should use it:

```
import ExternalizedPromiseCreator from '../externalized-promise';

describe('ExternalizedPromise', () => {
  let fn: jest.Mock;
  let deferredFn: jest.Mock;
  let neverCalledFn: jest.Mock;
  beforeEach(() => {
    fn = jest.fn();
    deferredFn = jest.fn();
    neverCalledFn = jest.fn();
  });

  it('resolve should resolve the promise', done => {
    const externalizedPromise = ExternalizedPromiseCreator.create(() => fn());

    externalizedPromise
      .promise
      .then(() => deferredFn())
      .catch(() => neverCalledFn())
      .then(() => {
        expect(deferredFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(neverCalledFn).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
        done();
      });

    expect(fn).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(neverCalledFn).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(deferredFn).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

    externalizedPromise.resolve();
  });
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As I didn't find what I was looking for, I will share what I actually wanted to achieve when I ended in this question.

**Scenario**: I have 3 different API's with same possible response and therefore I would like to handle the completion and error handling of the promises in a single function. This is what I did:

1. **Create a handler function:**

```js
  private handleHttpPromise = (promise: Promise<any>) => {
    promise
      .then((response: any) => {
        // do something with the response
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // do something with the error
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

2. **Send your promises to the created handler**

```js
  switch (method) {
    case 'get': {
      this.handleHttpPromise(apiService.get(url));
      break;
    }
    case 'post': {
      if (jsonData) {
        this.handleHttpPromise(apiService.post(url, jsonData));
      }
      break;
    }
    // (...)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share something different, an extension to this topic.

Sometimes you want a "task promise" to be automatically re-created at the same address (property or variable) when it resolves. It's possible to create an outside resolver that does just that.

Example of a recurring promise with an external resolver. Whenever the resolver is called, a new promise is created at the same address/variable/property.

```
let resolvePromise;
let thePromise;

const setPromise = (resolve) => {
  resolvePromise = () => {
    resolve();
    thePromise = new Promise(setPromise);   
  }
}
thePromise = new Promise(setPromise);

(async () => {
  let i = 0;
  while (true) {
    let msg = (i % 2 === 0) ? 'Tick' : 'Tock';
    document.body.innerHTML = msg;
    setTimeout(resolvePromise, 1000);
    await thePromise;
    i++;
  }
})();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h3zvw5xr

Answer (score 0):

For fun, you also combine a promise into a self-resolvable function:

```js
function Resolver() {
  let resolve;
  const promise = new Promise(r => resolve = r);
  return new Proxy(resolve, {
    get: (_, prop) => promise[prop].bind(promise)
  });
}

const resolve = Resolver();

(async () => {
  resolve
    .then(value => console.log('thenable:', value))
    .finally(() => console.log('finally'));
  const value = await resolve;
  console.log('awaitable:', value);
})()

resolve('test');
// thenable: test
// finally
// awaitable: test
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not against importing libraries, a very lightweight dependency you can use is `p-defer`: https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-defer

(With all these answers talking about deferred promises I'm surprised that not a single one mentions the awesome collection of promise modules by `sindresorhus` on GitHub / npm:
https://github.com/sindresorhus/promise-fun)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do :

```
let p: SuperPromise<void> = new SuperPromise();
p.resolve();
```

And this is the quite simple SuperPromise class I implemented :

```
export class SuperPromise<T> implements Promise<T> {

    public resolve: (value: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void;
    public reject: (reason?: any) => void;
    private promise: Promise<T> = new Promise<T>((resolve, reject) => { 
        this.resolve = resolve;
        this.reject = reject
    });

    then<TResult1 = T, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: T) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | null | undefined, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<TResult2>) | null | undefined): Promise<TResult1 | TResult2> {
        return this.promise.then(onfulfilled, onrejected);
    }

    catch<TResult = never>(onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult | PromiseLike<TResult>) | null | undefined): Promise<T | TResult> {
        return this.promise.catch(onrejected);
    }

    finally(onfinally?: (() => void) | null | undefined): Promise<T> {
        return this.promise.finally(onfinally);
    }

    get [Symbol.toStringTag](): string {
        return this.promise[Symbol.toStringTag];
    }

}
```

Answer (score -5):

first enable --allow-natives-syntax on browser or node

```js
const p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    if (someCondition){
        resolve();
    } else {
        reject();
    } 
});

onClick = function () {
    %ResolvePromise(p, value)
}
```