# Why is resolve not defined through closure inside a function called in a promise?

Tags: javascript, promise

Why is `resolve` not defined through closure inside of `myFunction` in the code below?

```
const myFunction = () => {
  resolve();
}

const p = new Promise((resolve) => {
  myFunction();
}

(node:1232) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): ReferenceError: resolve is not defined
```

Comment: `resolve` is defined in a scope. `myFunction` is not defined in that scope. Nothing particular to promises here; this is how scope works all the time.

Comment: Do you know of a programming language where that *would* work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolve Javascript Promise outside function scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26150232/resolve-javascript-promise-outside-function-scope)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because that's just not how scoping works in JavaScript. Scoping is a **lexical** thing, meaning that what's important is not the dynamic relationship between calling/called environments but the structure of the code and the nesting of declarations.

You can of course explicitly pass the `resolve` function reference to the other function:

```
const myFunction = (resolve) => {
  resolve();
}

const p = new Promise((resolve) => {
  myFunction(resolve);
})
```

Comment: Yes, I know about lexical scoping, and I missed the fact that myFunction2 is defined outside of myFunction, so it doesn't matter where it is called. Clarified now.