# How to resolve a Promise only after a state change

Tags: javascript, redux, polymer-3.x

I am trying to resolve a Promise only after a certain condition is met outside the promise:

```
class myClass extends ... {

    render() {
       ...
       this.fetch();
       ....
    }

    fetch(){
        Promise.all([
          ....,
          ....,
          ....
        ]).then( () => {
          // new Promise or somthing like that
          // wait for state changed to resolve it
        }
        ).then(
          // do something
        )
    }

    stateChanged(state){
        if(condition){
           // resolve promise from here
        }
    }

}
```

I tried to implement it in similar way to this question 
[Resolve Javascript Promise outside function scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26150232/resolve-javascript-promise-outside-function-scope)
but I do not understand

1. how we can call a variable
2. how to make this work inside my Class
   I tried it with a `this.waitForPromise = null` variable, but when I call 
   it later `this.waitForPromise()` I get a is not a function Type error.

```
class myClass extends ... {

    render() {
       ...
       this.fetch();
       ....
    }

    constructor(){
        this._waitForPromise = null;
    }

    fetch(){
        Promise.all([
          ....,
          ....,
          ....
        ]).then( () => {
            new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
              this._waitForPromise = resolve; 
            });
        }
        ).then(
          // do something
        )
    }

    stateChanged(state){
        if(condition){
           this._waitForPromise();
        }
    }

}
```

Any help and explanation is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a closure issue using `this`, so capture it first.

You should return the promise in your `then`.

You should check to see if promise is created when state changes.

Keep in mind you can only invoke one of resolve/reject, and only once.

```
class myClass extends ... {

    render() {
       ...
       this.fetch();
       ....
    }

    constructor(){
        this.resolve = null;
        this.state = null; // TODO initial state
    }

    fetch(){
        const that = this;
        Promise.all([
          ....,
          ....,
          ....
        ]).then( () => {
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
              that.resolve = resolve;
              that.checkState();
            });
        }
        ).then(
          // do something
        )
    }

    checkState(){
      if(condition && this.resolve){
         this.resolve();
         this.resolve = null;  // set to null to ensure we don't call it again.
      }
    }

    stateChanged(state){
        this.state = state;
        this.checkState();
    }

}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I tried but I receive a  'Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.resolve is not a function" error.

Comment: Did you capture `this` in a closure, and then reference it through `that`. `const that = this;`?  In your original code, `this` refers to the promise, and not the containing class.

Comment: I am not 100% sure to be honest I tried it exactly the way you wrote it and then also with `..),bind(this)` but I always get the "is not a function" error.
I think I get the Idea that we want to access the function scope of the Promise but I do not understand the concept behind `that.resolve = resolve;`.

Comment: that.resolve storing the resolve function in your class as a property.  Then you invoke it in `stateChanged`.  You will get a `is not a function` if your `this` is not pointing to your class when you assign it, and then call it from stateChanged.

Comment: Put a console.log(this) inside of stateChanged, fetch, and your Promise, and confirm they are all the same.

Comment: Ok, thanks so much that helped a lot for the understanding.
So the problem seems to be that the Promise does not exist yet when I try to call `this.resolvse()` as the `Promise.all` was not fulfilled for all conditions yet.
I tried putting it into directly into the Promise.all but no luck yet I will try a bit later or tomorrow morning.

Comment: You can put logic in the promise to resolve it if the state is set.  I will update solution.  You can see that `checkState` is called from both places to ensure there is no race condition.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I'm not all that familiar with Polymer 3, but I'm fluent in Polymer 1 and 2.

I'm getting that you want to do this:

1. Get an ajax promise.
2. Return said ajax promise once a certain state has changed.
3. do a fetch call if said promise hasn't been done.

What you need to do is to save your promise as a variable, and then just chain it together with other method calls. The comments below explains more about what I'm doing with your example code from the OP.

```
class myClass extends ... {

render() {
   ...
   this.fetch();
   ....
}

fetch(){
    this.set('savedPromise', Promise.all([ // save promise to variable 
      ....,
      ....,
      ....
    ])
    // not needed
    /* .then( () => {
      // new Promise or somthing like that
      // wait for state changed to resolve it
    }*/
    ).then(
      // do something

      return result // added this line
    )
}

stateChanged(state){
    if(condition){
       if (this.savedPromise) {
         this.savedPromise.then(function(response) {
           // handle data
         });
       else {
         fetch().then(function(response) {  // if set before render(), do a fetch call.
           // handle data
         }
       }
    }
}
```

}