# Create a Promise that resolves when variable is not undefined

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, settimeout

I'm trying to Create a Promise that resolves when variable is not **undefined**.

**Code example**

https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-feynman-ktvox?file=/src/index.js

```
let fetchedPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const check = ()=>{
    setTimeout(() =>{
    console.log("checking")
    if (dataFetched) resolve(dataFetched);
    else check()
    }, 100);
  }
  check()
});

const waitForDataFromAnotherComponent = async () => {
  let result = await fetchedPromise;
  console.log("Result: ", result);
};

const assignData = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    dataFetched = 1000;
    console.log(dataFetched);
  }, 5000)
};

waitForDataFromAnotherComponent();
assignData();
```

This works but I find it inefficient as it's callstack prone and seems wrong.

Other non-working solutions I've tried:

```
//-------------SOLUTION 1
let fetchedPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const check = ()=>{
    if (dataFetched) resolve(dataFetched);
    else check()
  }
  check()
});

//--------------------SOLUTION 2
let fetchedPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   if (dataFetched) resolve(dataFetched);
});
```

**Scenario**

I need a function like solution 3 that doesn't rely on setTimeout

Comment: [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) is likely what you want.

Comment: There's no way that `assignData` may accept a callback or return a promise itself…!?

Comment: @Sirko how can I integrate mutationObserver in my Code?

`

const callback = function(observer) {
  if(observer) console.log("Observer is ", observer)
}
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback)
observer.observe(dataFetched);


`
this returns node error on observer

Comment: `assignData` is just a *fake* function that represents the fact that the variable is changed.
In my "real" code there is a function that assigns a value to  `assignData`

Comment: It's clear that this is an example for example's sake. I want to make sure you're not barking up the wrong tree entirely and are missing the easy option of something like `assignData().then(...)`.

Comment: In order to make my structure clear, i'll explain it to you:
i have a useFetch Hook (a function if you're not familiar with react) that fetches api, assigns data fetched  to a variable(a useState variable) and returns the data itself.

I have a React Context (it's like a  global object) that registers these api calls.

if 2 useFetch functions are called at the same time with the same signature(same input in the function), i have a method that checks if there's an api in 'pending fetch' state so that one of the 2 usefetch function doesn't fetch data but *waits* for the other function

Comment: As i can see MutationObserver is for DOM changes, instead, maybe [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)
could get the work done

Comment: I would think there's a better, perhaps React-specific way to handle this rather than trying to observe an individual variable. I can't give any detailed advice on that though without knowing more details, and even then I'm not a React guy…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using Javascript Proxy

Basically I assign a Proxy Object to dataFetched that listens to changes.
I re-create the function of listening due to the fact that it must include `resolve()`

```
let dataFetched
let x = {
  aListener: function (val) {},
  set a(val) {
    dataFetched = val;
    this.aListener(val);
  },
  get a() {
    return dataFetched;
  },
  registerListener: function (listener) {
    this.aListener = listener;
  }
};

let fetchedPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  x.registerListener(function (val) {
    console.log("yeyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy");
    if (dataFetched) resolve(dataFetched);
  });
});

const waitForDataFromAnotherComponent = async () => {
  let result = await fetchedPromise;
  console.log("Result: ", result);
};
const assignData = async () => {
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    setTimeout(() => {
      x.a = 1000;
      console.log(dataFetched);
      resolve(dataFetched);
    }, 1000)
  );
};

waitForDataFromAnotherComponent();
assignData();
```

**EDIT**

Actually it's possible to externalize the `resolve()` function of the promise but with some downsides as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26150232/resolve-javascript-promise-outside-function-scope)

**example**

```
let dataFetched
var promiseResolve, promiseReject;

let x = {
  aListener: function (val) {
    if (dataFetched) promiseResolve(dataFetched);
},
  set a(val) {
    dataFetched = val;
    this.aListener(val);
  },
  get a() {
    return dataFetched;
  },
  registerListener: function (listener) {
    this.aListener = listener;
  }
};

let fetchedPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 promiseResolve = resolve;
  promiseReject = reject;
});
```