# Better alternative to "promisify"-ing?

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, promise, future

Let's say I'm writing the following function:

```js
async function foo(axe: Axe): Promise<Sword> {
  // ...
}
```

It is meant to be used like this:

```js
async function bar() {
  // get an axe somehow ...

  const sword = await foo(axe);

  // do something with the sword ...
}
```

So far, so good. The problem is that in order to implement foo, I want to call the following "callback-style async" function. I cannot change its signature (it's a library/module):

```js
/* The best way to get a sword from an axe!
 * Results in a null if axe is not sharp enough */
function qux(axe: Axe, callback: (sword: Sword) => void);
```

The best way I've found to do this is to ["promisify"](https://javascript.info/promisify) qux:

```js
async function foo(axe: Axe): Promise<Sword> {
  return new Promise<Sword>((resolve, reject) => {
    qux(axe, (sword) => {
      if (sword !== null) {
        resolve(sword);
      } else {
        reject('Axe is not sharp enough ;(');
      }
    });
  });
}
```

It works, but I was hoping I could do something more direct/readable. In some languages, you could create a promise-like object (I call it `Assure` here), and then explicitly set its value elsewhere. Something like this:

```js
async function foo(axe: Axe): Promise<Sword> {
  const futureSword = new Assure<Sword>();

  qux((sword) => {
    if (sword !== null) {
      futureSword.provide(sword);
    } else {
      futureSword.fail('Axe is not sharp enough ;(');
    }
  });

  return futureSword.promise;
```

Is this possible in the language itself, or do I need to use a library/module, like [deferred](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deferred)?

### Update (1): extra motivation

Why would one prefer the second solution over the first? Because of callback chaining.

What if I wanted to perform multiple steps inside foo, not just call qux? If this was synchronous code, it could look like this:

```js
function zim(sling: Sling): Rifle {
  const bow = bop(sling);
  const crossbow = wug(bow);
  const rifle = kek(crossbow); 
  return rifle;
}
```

If these functions were async, promisify-ing would give me this:

```js
async function zim(sling: Sling): Promise<Rifle> {
  return new Promise<Rifle>((resolve, reject) => {
    bop(sling, (bow) => {
      wug(bow, (crossbow) => {
        kek(crossbow, (rifle) => {
          resolve(rifle);
        });
      });
    });
  );
}
```

With an `Assure`, I could do this:

```js
async function zim(sling: Sling): Promise<Rifle> {
  const futureBow = new Assure<Bow>();
  bop(sling, (bow) => futureBow.provide(bow));

  const futureCrossbow = new Assure<Crossbow>();
  wug(await futureBow, (crossbow) => futureCrossbow.provide(crossbow));

  const futureRifle = new Assure<Rifle>();
  kek(await futureCrossbow, (rifle) => futureRifle.provide(rifle));
 
  return futureRifle;
}
```

I find this more manageable, since I don't need to keep track of the nested scopes and to worry about the order of computation. If functions take multiple arguments the difference is even larger.

#### Reflection

That said, I could agree that there is an elegance to the version with the nested calls, because we don't need to declare all these temporary variables.

And while writing this question I got another idea, of how I could keep in stride with the spirit of JavaScript:

```js
function zim(sling: Sling): Rifle {
  const bow = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => { bop(sling, resolve); });
  const crossbow = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => { wug(bow, resolve); });
  const rifle = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => { kek(crossbow, resolve); }); 
  return rifle;
}
```

... which starts to look a lot like using `util.promisify` from Nodejs. If only the callbacks were following the error-first convention... But at this point it seems justified to implement a naive `myPromisify` which wraps `promisify` and handles the type of callbacks I have.

Comment: looks like your `Assure` is just an abstracted promisify.

Comment: I would argue that it is a decision in the language itself (JavaScript) to not expose the resolve / reject outside of the Promise itself, you can read more about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26150232/resolve-javascript-promise-outside-the-promise-constructor-scope

Comment: Use a promise library that exposes resolve/reject. Or write your own simple wrapper that does it. TBH, I'm not really sure why the second code is any more preferable to the the first. I'd have just used used a generic `promisify` helper function instead. It's available in Node.js by default through `utils.promisify()`

Comment: Introducing a library with a different promise type just to write `promisify` in a slightly different way doesn’t seem worth it to me. Like VLAZ said, you probably want a `promisify` function, but the manual version is perfectly readable to anyone familiar with promises.

Comment: Ah, I knew I should motivate my preference a little better. Writing an update... (1)

Comment: Thanks, @AngYC, this is the question I was looking for, but didn't find, so I wrote my own. So the answer is basically "no, it is not possible in the language itself."

Comment: "*Because of callback chaining.*" that's because your approach is wrong. You're falling into the trap of [Aren't promises just callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22539815) whereas, if you promisify each function, then the chain auto-flattens and you can easily sequence them together: https://tsplay.dev/mp04am

Comment: The last paragraph of the question has the answer. Create one promisfy function that can do the job with this specific function signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Assure` Can be implemented pretty simply in TypeScript:

```typescript
class Assure<T, U = unknown> {
    public promise: Promise<T>;
    private resolve!: (value: T) => void;
    private reject! : (error: U) => void;

    constructor() {
        this.promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.resolve = resolve;
            this.reject = reject;
        });
    }

    public provide(value: T) {
        this.resolve(value);
    }

    public fail(reason: U) {
        this.reject(reason);
    }
}
```

[Playground Link with demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCUFcBOBTAPAFQDTQKrQF5oEA7AaxIHsB3EgPmgG8AoaN6ABwQCMQBLYJySUAtnwgoAXNAAKwsRMx0A3K3YckfAG5gALimioIlEFpQBCaQAodIBFOgYAlIQZbKfACar2Q7XoNUACsUYF1zaGsUJGEkaVwXAjcPb2Y1NmBKEghdJAQwyiQrFxZfX10AC3EAOg1RcQMiEhRqWXkGqysjEzMcYNDdRIZSstHKmu7TRsMUYymfUbLxiGr+sMIZkLCF0YBfJx3oXbTfLl4BIUotLxQbMDsHZyZ0paqVybM7h4OX45ez-iCABmYD4IC6KEgWXiJRe5TeqxQW10EKhJB+vmOfz4JH0SBBwAMAGVqIVPM9fMAwCQibowNxpLl7IcqiBdAAZFAkADmlWkJAQIm40VU2Nx0QJBlgAA8DCMMtTafTpCCQBJDhAKmAkBxmlB+YLhUhRWlPKFwKhoEDSGE+FloABHBDSqxgWXSGUoHBUkAgbhgYBkawQUlITzSElk6AAH2gAt9Q2g7i8TmkydSzEgAE8SMCbbo7SQrZRKK73XBZam2vVFJGw8M1JlsrorQhdMgUHXyU0WnBEKg0F26MVVGonS63V7oFYQ2TE-LoHwgdPZ2HoOYCE0EAmKWVre3UF3asJrmaZ6HPBj2LtoCg1XK4a2D52L9UQWCrAByT2LmBUFuatqHC3lQCDchU0DKF+V5sMcsE-GoqAHkW+4dkedQKCgopAA)

With that said, it is probably not needed. The usage ends up being basically like using promises, however:

1. It is not idiomatic.
2. Does not seem to bring any value over regular promises.

A much better alternative might be to define a function that can turn callback taking functions into promise returning function. This is also not much work - with TS we can even make sure the converted functions have the correct types. Here is an implementation for the major types of callback taking functions:

```typescript
/* utility types */
/** All but last elements of a tuple: [a, b, c, d] -> [a, b, c] */
type Initial<T extends any[]> = T extends [ ...infer Initial, any ] ? Initial : any[];
/** All but first elements of a tuple: [a, b, c, d] -> [b, c, d] */
type Tail<T extends any[]> = T extends [ any, ...infer Tail ] ? Tail : any[];

/** First elements of a tuple: [a, b, c, d] -> a */
type Head<T extends any[]> = T extends [ infer Head, ...any[] ] ? Head : any;
/** Last elements of a tuple: [a, b, c, d] -> d */
type Last<T extends any[]> = T extends [ ...any[], infer Last ] ? Last : any;

/** First parameter of a function: ( (a, b, c, d) => any ) -> a */
type FirstParameter<T extends (...args: any[]) => void> = Head<Parameters<T>>;
/** Last parameter of a function: ( (a, b, c, d) => any ) -> d */
type LastParameter<T extends (...args: any[]) => void> = Last<Parameters<T>>;
/* /utility types */

/**
 * Converts an asynchronous function to a promise returning one.
 * The function should have a callback with a result as last parameter
 */
function promisifyResultCallback<T extends (...args: any[]) => void>(fn: T) {
    type ResultCallback = LastParameter<T>;
    type ReturnType = FirstParameter<ResultCallback>;

    return function(...args: Initial<Parameters<T>>): Promise<ReturnType> {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            fn(...args, resolve);
        });
    }
}

/**
 * Converts an asynchronous function to a promise returning one.
 * The function should have a callback with an error and result as last parameter - error-first style like in Node.js
 */
function promisifyErrorFirstCallback<T extends (...args: any[]) => void>(fn: T) {
    type ResultCallback = LastParameter<T>;
    type ReturnType = LastParameter<ResultCallback>;

    return function(...args: Initial<Parameters<T>>): Promise<ReturnType> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fn(...args, (err: unknown, x: ReturnType) => {
                if (err) 
                    reject(err);
                
                resolve(x);
            });
        });
    }
}

/**
 * Converts an asynchronous function to a promise returning one.
 * The function should have two callback at the end  for success and error
 */
function promisifyTwoCallbacks<T extends (...args: any[]) => void>(fn: T) {
    type ResultCallback = Last<Initial<Parameters<T>>>; //second to last
    type ReturnType = FirstParameter<ResultCallback>;

    return function(...args: Initial<Initial<Parameters<T>>>): Promise<ReturnType> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fn(...args, resolve, reject);
        });
    }
}
```

Which allows usage like this:

```
declare function onlyResultCallback(a: string, b: number, callback: (resut: boolean) => void): void;
const p_onlyResultCallback = promisifyResultCallback(onlyResultCallback);
//    ^ type is: (a: string, b: number) => Promise<boolean>

declare function errorFirstCallback(a: string, b: number, callback: (err: Error | null, resut: boolean) => void): void;
const p_errorFirstCallback = promisifyErrorFirstCallback(errorFirstCallback);
//    ^ type is: (a: string, b: number) => Promise<boolean>

declare function twoCallbacks(a: string, b: number, onSuccess: (resut: boolean) => void, onError: (err: Error) => void): void;
const p_twoCallbacks = promisifyTwoCallbacks(twoCallbacks);
//    ^ type is: (a: string, b: number) => Promise<boolean>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgBArgLglgNjKBPMyAOBTAzmEwBQo4AgnHGAEbRhwCGWUYGcGAthgHZQ4D2AZmFqoIaFgC4wAbVoAaSnIDGcgCYBdMAFoAfFNnywC9XnzoMYAJIdEMWnAA8AFSYAPKJ2U5aHJJNU6AvGBOGK7uOJJgAHTRMBx8GABOFlawtnJeKOoA-MnWtmASGb4A3IQgJGSU1HwwCQxMLOxcvAJCUCLiunIUiirq2lI9Bn24BKZBtPCOLm4cHoLevgFBM2FSC0hy0ZGx8UkOk+TZE-AFGyX4ZeAAYrX1zGyc3GD8gsKiGBLS3b1gapo6ITGcYACQwtGU0xCs3mRT8YECwVCc3CYF2iTAYIhW2icLAxyxyjOGVKRDAABl6IwHk1nq82h1Pl19Eo-v0dETgUhMBSqVDkbDFvDEasUettnC5OikpT6sdZYxCt5SlcwLc6ow0LQErR2G4kvSwHwIBwFLAeBwJAAKMBWvRDVnKACUCMB3jALoGQLG3LM6oYAAVtbqMPr+TCcFaJQkAOZYJU+VQu-w6ABuPBgymWhLsQZ1esSWEcWi0pPKvPqWvzoYxhuNpvNltttvtv2dro2HoBf1GJl9FageZDYaREdt0bjCd8ybTGazCIHueDBbqxdLZTAwGg8EQKFMOGMV3wuDAAGELanEs8vIIsEhTQALBIWngQHD1s0wC2oHhvNDP1gYCwMwElDCAEisDgYxeDgMEiY9wAcB8zA-RswCwB9XzgIkH1oS83gUWw4AoWgFAAazAAB3RAHzeUCsAgOBGHoGgqTAKth0SBCCFQr8OHYgCgJgPgkAAJWwRioFPIiSPI8M1ijXFY3jc4kw7dNMy0K0+CbBwXQAb2PMBjPGcSGKY6SyFkijAgVIcV2LUpjJM-txPaCCHH7QJ-UHZcawSOwzMkyziNIsj1yM4zQPc-jeItRTIm1SdclSex7P8osHBLJ0JADQTgMCsCPN9HRDOc8qwGi8D+NgyiwDynhAOAq0rXong4EvGcwDKirep0hKkqwOQ2o6jAnSc3qwAAX3GyLpvwKbLiIBCzwvK9PH4+h7wUJ8XzfI0TU-b8oF-IR-0aoCQKKyDoItOCVqQlDDrQjCsJwvCzCEQirLCqiaIWJgEmfJIvCJejJNvVjKz8-VNEB4GNBqDV0OQFgaBgMizFiMAADkeGUOCACssG4-A4v486muEpAAFEgZ4BIfJC6z5LFAblKnNSUzADSs203SDLm0yJIsmTftsql0pHddyuFmLPJ5CXAxhxJCvMqSxfIiLyqqiCDobPj2eSyw8jSlXVyyrQcvq-KMEK+WSu6uadeusBapti7mta7B2svYaMEJjAzS6nrJuc-qJyG21EgSCQTTIjgeEojg5GcCQ3OqhWxo7UOw4q4To6Bl1nbz3rQMDs0rRj2bS96kvS5Gy8rWcGva5mibevbubFsWo8T3PDhLwSa9NrvR9n0T-byZ-P9bcq67Ylu2D4JPR79aO-jXsY978KgSjf2+0LyMERgoGQpg5mMvgGfQiAFAUbANqJGOGdJ6fKaEkSHH35mwsy0V5hGxUnCLqvMtI6QkHpJ2stXIiw1j9Y+SsoB2BNqlJc1Z9SZRLKWTcwBgIKAtESE6UMoBC1gQ7RWao7i+QwarIKosEHhRVC7GK69GxAIkKgmw9guG2HQZxC22DrYNSanbDOxVMClXrvPVh7sRGXRao3DA-sK5QBDtI8qEclJxn9lgX2yj56qNbp3Yx81e4EwUHQUCbC+IwTgGJOBv9yJ2gkAwBIi9ugSA4BAVgFBEiKE1mRa04MoASAoDwdq4IOCgLnNbXmpQCEcErAAfQtPY+h8Cj42QEp7amGSnFkStGkhx6sCmzWAMAcqAA9LIlwLFWKegbb8L9GbUIKS4lG7ioKeLdj4vxCQAmMOtDHCQdNgZgAAD69LILo6AYSIksC8DEzMcS5wJItCklpTNAkLg-lgamYyGbbMYVXemrSNRlNJJU5yNS6lBwaTY46P9AlYA6W4jxlAvF9P8TBAAynfB+WAVLewYqEygCyonLOUHIC0hzY6F3hXCqFqzMzrKSZqZJe8eAFJwIEPZ1Nv7YpeVaLFOLynXOMjUoAA)

With a promisify function, `foo()` can be implemented as simple as:

```typescript
declare function qux(axe: Axe, callback: (sword: Sword | null) => void): void;

async function foo(axe: Axe): Promise<Sword> {
  const p_qux = promisifyResultCallback(qux);
  const maybeSword = await p_qux(axe);

  if (maybeSword === null)
    throw 'Axe is not sharp enough ;(';
  
  // the maybeSword is narrowed to just a sword since null is eliminated in the `if`
  return maybeSword;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=51&ssc=2&pln=37&pc=1#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIEkB2BLUyCGAbAPAFVtAB6jSIAmAzrOouANoC6AfLALyz5EnlV2wB0g5IgBm0AE4IUaLABpqtWA1gB+KagyZYALgX0GAbjBQ4udMhydipSnsYt2V7rb41w8wf2FjJZi0tUOcy1dN0YjYxhYAAlodDI8AmseO2Y2DiTnXlhvCRi4sg9BMOVlNVj4nT0jCCiAGXQKUESuGyoShwzWlL5PN3lcyQamgLVh0Cq3CNq4ADFkcSaABXRxdABbaBJxFuTbAAo+8QBzClDaRgBKNhYANwB7ZDJOioSVtc3tijwmJhqTWDjd4bLYSXZZWCHYonM6pa6sO6PZ7pcbYYGfCTfXC-CIAegAVPjgLB8bAAML3RC3CSgdqIagUcCIADGAAtxJT7gBXKgiLkstCU2Cge7UWCQDnrZAUODiLZc8QoRDHWCU6D8Ymk3CsuB8gXIIUUVnczBkWCs9DUsXMrCYABG6GZAGtYAB3VCssVyihczATRqwTCNCaQVYg7aa3HAPXMwX0iX3KUUZAicAAJWgPr9ZNtDud4LakKOp3O+nhiKeTH2IkQulw1wA3sTYC2ZrAM1nQDnMPbHS72ECwxidtijC3WwCM6BxPzcAD2PNFqB0aCdh3fV3c32-iBx7A5aAFfSY3GofxViX1DIcCuvj8mJddEtJdLoNgpzPEHOYCwm3u9weR6wIg0CurAz6Jq++z7N69yYNS5awH+-4oTWZ4XhQ8iwfB0CXGOKGwAAvnhzYtoRwDkcAwjbCIjpwAAyq69ziGayEtjaiD0aA6B2ro05ctA+EtqyFigHUpDHKArK6IgXLrHaEhGJR1ESLRzJwAAgoQcBsbAHFcTxui0ZgMpCbARqrJAIEULCsnyYpFEgGQ0DMkGcqwCeBr0gAjlyhD7Og2m6Fp0DyDaPZ5k6uj7BQTEsbojHMWaAA+wG+pgiEPE8j6wFlZARI0TLMh5-Kxl5Hn3PcAVBbAIU5RBSZvolLG-s2zKUiMkAAPq+YQ6QJkmKbppmG7dr2zr7L1JEtriuJ7gAeiobUdRM6zoOACnNWa7DoK65ghj1fnVbh+GzQtS3NimkJrRt0BbWwrDsLJPaXKRwrsvcYEAOQhTkVCIPcEwWeIkAEADXLHJ6Bj7F9+HNmdUlwDdm1xWa0rAasHKutAZoirAABWPL+uZqPmcI6lpT2f0EJgyBSog6AkGj9KI7AAAGKZs82gGKrAyN3ajp1zeOi0UUAA)

The assignment to `p_qux` is just here for demonstration purposes. A more idiomatic code would either make the assignment outside the function once or just directly use `const maybeSword = await promisifyResultCallback(qux)(axe);`

if really needed, the promisifying function can be changed to also allow for passing arguments and allow usage like `promisifyResultCallback(qux, axe)` however, that is left as an exercise of the reader.

Using promises also eliminates the nesting issue:

```typescript
declare function bop( sling   : Sling   , callback: (bow: Bow          ) => void ): void;
declare function wug( bow     : Bow     , callback: (crossbow: Crossbow) => void ): void;
declare function kek( crossbow: Crossbow, callback: (rifle: Rifle      ) => void ): void;

async function zim(sling: Sling): Promise<Rifle> {
  return new Promise<Rifle>((resolve, reject) => {
    bop(sling, (bow) => {
      wug(bow, (crossbow) => {
        kek(crossbow, (rifle) => {
          resolve(rifle);
        });
      });
    });
  });
}
```

once the functions are promisified:

```typescript
const p_bop = promisifyResultCallback(bop);
const p_wug = promisifyResultCallback(wug);
const p_kek = promisifyResultCallback(kek);
```

can be handled as regular promises:

```typescript
function zim(sling: Sling) {
    return p_bop(sling)
        .then(bow => p_wug(bow))
        .then(crossbow => p_kek(crossbow))
}
```

or

```typescript
function zim(sling: Sling) {
    return p_bop(sling)
        .then(p_wug)
        .then(p_kek)
}
```

or

```typescript
async function zim(sling: Sling) {
    const bow = await p_bop(sling);
    const crossbow = await p_wug(bow);
    const rifle = await p_kek(crossbow);
    return rifle;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgS2AghgGwDwBUoQB7ARwAmAzlCnCANoC6AfFALxQ76EnnVQB0fCcAGYQATrETJ0AGgpUotKAH5xSVGigAuWTVoBuAFChIrFAkxsCRMtrqMWFjte6UQMvjwHCxWU+oXKfM00bPX1DcGgACQgUYmxcS04Qu1YExy4oT1EoaNi3Phc6eSUcmOJglwMjaAAZFFJgePYrckKGZlTmpO53FxkssTqG4uUh4AqqA3DjADEEEQaABRQRFABbCEIRJsTrAApekQBzUi02gEpmRgA3AHsEYhTcuOXVja3SbHp6KoioMde602oh26SgBwKx1OIUuTBu90eHTGGEB71Enyw3ymAHoAFS4-RQXFQADCtzg11EwFacAopBAcAAxgALETk24AV3Igg5TOQ5KgwFuFCgYDZawQpGgIk2HJEiDgRyg5IgPEJxKwzOgPL5CAFpGZnLQ5WZKEpIsZ6DQACMUIyANZQADuSGZIplpA5aHG9SgaHq4zAKyBW3V2P0OsZ-NpYtuEtICEEIAAShBPd6SVbbQ7QS1wYcTmcqHRYfCHvQ9oI4FosJcAN6EqBN6pQVPp4CZtA2u2OlgA4No7aYgxN5t-VPAES8rB-FhzBbAVHA7Ztr0drM9n5hUdQGXAOW0yPRiE8FaFlSSTBLj5fejnLSLcWSiAYCdTuAzyCMBs7nd7g9QHAEBOlAj5xs+ex7B6txoJSpZQD+v5IVWJ5nqQMjQbBEDnCOSFQAAvjhjZNvh+ikfoAhbIIdrQAAymgAhKohTaSvRjFaJOHIQLoUDYtipBxtAsaQCIoCCsKawoPa0BIIB5IALQQGsYCgGRFFwFRNFQAAQrcIHMZkpC6U6HFTtxvH8YJopsiJYlClAknSZk4xwApSkqSAamUaI1GMtAJJsqQpDWnpCHEYZAW3EFIUmYKZk8XxAkbNZty2SA4kOVJMkuW5ymqaR3kiL50DJomaDQAZkqlYI5WmVxCWWclwlUul9mOdlclwIpeWeeRxAQIy-oylAR56rSIVgHsUCkAxiqjlobFzU2MiWl22b2loewxVoxl4aO8F3A8UD3lAh3EAY-WDSs2q8lGY3OhyRxTTFv47aFO4rRuDqbYygXBXpWiRdFekHQix1aGdF0DUNN26gK0n2lNv1Rf9sVA6jn1rT2m0iGVEBaNV5VIaDR0nZDYR8bcuNHAI6AUGAsZ2sy+j1AyjIjbd0ZQAAXggawAPpAQ0EDEHsM3sVAi1HCdYHxi+hMQN+jb-vKgHAaBT5Sq+eMVlBaYwZSGEQAAVgNwDwQZE1i7NRwyFtINXGFSFOo99tOnbyPA06FvhTuCN7J7GPgrjNXYY7BlIZhlJQXjRF7YRuE7gn4XJyRRHkXxsbxomCAixzcNwKc+iMuSwxgPzE0dFnkqJimaZrp23YOvbYBESXheBvzLtKiw1cJkmq4Zl9iPd23pedwjVea7Xg-rljzcI0REac-dvMC33EAkqaAiMdbEtS-W4UqzGFepXvirnL7o48MAWpwG7jvl93bvnJfe033fAd-S9cKivz-uBxiq-NSy8C48z5vzDeW9TAKiOGSJkEFxaKgWjbQ+f5ZSq3LlbJB0sr5Ng-kQPYT9HpvzwgQ++5dF4gNZkyfOd0BRr35jQxkABBJ0phRY4JQYxNBo527DB-hQdhsksFnxwXHPh48oCANCiwFAwjO7PyAYnaRUiQ5EzkQov+ADv4gxUcfXceMDD4SAA)