# Resolve or reject a promise outside the promise object

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I want to finish a promise task outside the task itself, just like some language can kill process/thread. Seeing from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26150232/resolve-javascript-promise-outside-the-promise-constructor-scope), I implemented my code as below. However, the promise still continues after counting to 5. I would be grateful if somebody can help me with this.

```
let resolveCurrentPromise = () => {};

const longTimeHandler = async () => {
  let counter = 0;
  while (true) {
    console.log(counter++);
    await new Promise((res) => {
      setTimeout(res, 1000);
    });
    if (counter === 5) {
      resolveCurrentPromise();
    }
  }
};

(async () => {
  await new Promise((res) => {
    resolveCurrentPromise = res;
    longTimeHandler();
  });
})();
```

Comment: You never break out of the `while` loop.

Comment: Add `break` after the call to `resolveCurrentPromise()`.

Comment: Why are you even `await`ing the `new Promise` if you do nothing afterwards?

Comment: *"However, the promise still continues after counting to 5."*: no, the promise resolved. It is your `while` loop that keeps going on. It is quite easy to see with debugging that your promise resolved...