# Does deferred.resolve() wait until the previous line completes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does deferred.resolve() wait until the line before it completes? My code works, but I can't tell if deferred.resolve() is actually happening after the image finishes loading or if it's executing after the request for the image is initiated but before it finishes loading.

```js
test = function(deferred) {
  $('<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/72/%27Calypso%27_Panorama_of_Spirit%27s_View_from_%27Troy%27_%28Stereo%29.jpg">');
  deferred.resolve();
};

$.when($.Deferred(test)).then(function() {
  document.location = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or do I need to add a load handler to the image like so?

```js
test = function(deferred) {
  $('<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/72/%27Calypso%27_Panorama_of_Spirit%27s_View_from_%27Troy%27_%28Stereo%29.jpg">').on("load", function() {
    deferred.resolve();
  });
};

$.when($.Deferred(test)).then(function() {
  document.location = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The problem I've found with adding an .on("load", handler) is if the image fails to load for some reason, deferred.resolve() is never executed. I tested this with using a bad url.

I need to be able to guarantee that the page redirect happens after the image loads, but also that the image won't block the redirect from happening if there is an error loading the image.

Comment: Add an `.on("error")` handler as well.

Comment: `Does deferred.resolve() wait until the previous line completes?`  it does if it's not `async` but reading what your saying your wanting to wait for onload, so no it won't do that automatically for you.

Comment: @Keith good to know, thanks!

Comment: @Archer that seems to solve my problem. If you submit it as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: I've linked a question that already answers the same issue.  Glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

load event is asynchronous, to make sure that next line executes after the completion of image loading, indeed you need to add the handler.

See this for more info,
[jQuery .load(function) synchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975331/jquery-loadfunction-synchronous)